# 1-n relationship

Tags: database, relationships

I dont get 1-n relationship.

I have read some articles but still cant figure it out.

I get 1-many, 1:1 and many-to-many.

But what does 1-n mean?

Comment: Wow. Three almost identical answers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1-n is the same as 1-many

Answer (score 2):

1-n is the same as 1-many. *n* is just another way of representing an unknown "many".

Answer (score 2):

`n` could be any number, so this is equivalent to 1:many

Answer (score 2):

Its just another way to say 1 to many

Answer (score 0):

It's another way of expressing a "parent-child" or "master-detail" relationship. For everything parent you have an undefined number (meaning it can lie between 1 and something-bigger-than-one) of children.

Comment: that's a misleading way of thinking of it.  there's a 1:N relationship between `S` and `SP`, yet neither is child or detail of the other.